# Dockerfile ENV not available during container run

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, dropwizard, aws-codepipeline

I have a Dropwizard project that I am deploying using AWS Codepipeline with below stages:

- Source
- Build(CodeBuild)
- Deploy(ECS)

I have this below Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/maven:3.8.4-amazoncorretto-17 AS build

WORKDIR /var/server

ARG EXECUTION_ENV
ENV ENV_VARIABLE_ENVIRONMENT ${EXECUTION_ENV}
RUN echo $ENV_VARIABLE_ENVIRONMENT

ADD pom.xml /var/server/pom.xml
ADD src /var/server/src

RUN mvn clean install

ADD config.yml  /var/server/

FROM public.ecr.aws/amazoncorretto/amazoncorretto:17

WORKDIR /var/server
COPY --from=build /var/server/target/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /var/server/target/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY --from=build /var/server/config.yml /var/server/config.yml

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "target/server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", "server", "config.yml"]
```

Within my application, I have configured the below

```
bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(
                new SubstitutingSourceProvider(path -> Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path),
                        new EnvironmentVariableSubstitutor(false)));
```

When i run the pipeline, i observed that the environment variable ENV_VARIABLE_ENVIRONMENT prints the correct value that is passed to it using CodeBuild's environment variable. However, within the application, when i try `System.getenv("ENV_VARIABLE_ENVIRONMENT")`, that returns null.

Why is the environment variable not available in the container when the app is run?

Comment: You're using a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). Each stage has its own separate environment.

Answer (score 0):

In Docker, there are run time ENV and build time ENV so you can't retrieve your build time ENV when the app is running.

You can set run time ENV when you edit container in Task Definition at section ENVIRONMENT with environment variables or even environment files (the files is saved in S3)